# function using the row summation with grep gives an error in R

Tags: r, function

I have come across a typical problem. I have been using a line of code in R as follows:

```
myfiles3a <- lapply(myfiles3, function(x) {
    x$CHINA2 <- rowSums(x[,grep("China", names(x))], na.rm = T); x
})
```

It gives me perfect result flawlessly applied since I wrote it. But, today when I just wanted to the same thing for another country `Japan` or `Russia`. The code gives an error. like `Error in rowSums(x[, grep("Russia", names(x))], na.rm = T) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`

I am totally clueless why it's happening. My new line of code is as follows.

```
myfiles3c <- lapply(myfiles3, function(x) {x$RUSSIA2 <- rowSums(x[,grep("Russia", names(x))], na.rm = T); x})
```

I am unable to find where I have gone wrong in the two lines of code.

Comment: The issue would be because one of the `list` element is not a matrix or data.frame, but a `vector`.  Please check `sapply(myfiles3, class)`  Also, possible that you don't find any column with 'Russia' in one of the datasets.  Wrap with a `tryCatch` and bypass those error issues

Comment: out is as follows `[1] "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame" "data.frame"
[10] "data.frame" "data.frame"`

Comment: In that case, it is the second issue, that one or more of the datasets doesn't have the `Russia' thing in their column name

Comment: No this is not the case all dataframes in each is `list(255x239)`.

Comment: `dplyr` package makes this sort of code cleaner, something vaguely like: `x %>% filter(country=='China') %>% summarize(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By going through the error, the crux of the issue is the `?Extract` behavior which uses `drop = TRUE` by default.  What happens is that when we specify `,`, it gets coerced from data.frame to `vector` when there is a single column.  Consider the following the example, where there is only a single column with 'Russia' in the names

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
df1$RussiaCol <- 1:5
rowSums(df1[,grep("Russia", names(df1))], na.rm = TRUE)
```

> Error in rowSums(df1[, grep("Russia", names(df1))], na.rm = TRUE) : 
>         'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

---

Now, let's check the issue

```
df1[,grep("Russia", names(df1))]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

returns a `vector` due to the default behavior

```
df1[,grep("Russia", names(df1)), drop = FALSE]
#   RussiaBot
#1         1
#2         2
#3         3
#4         4
#5         5
```

Or without using any `,`, by default it takes the index as the column index

```
df1[grep("Russia", names(df1))]
```

According to `?rowSums`

> x - an array of two or more dimensions, containing numeric, complex, integer or logical values, or a numeric data frame. For .colSums() etc, a numeric, integer or logical matrix (or vector of length m * n).

So, it won't take a vector

---

In the `list`, if we remove the `,` it should work fine

```
lapply(myfiles3, function(x) {
       x$RUSSIA2 <- rowSums(x[grep("Russia", names(x))], na.rm = T)
       x})
```

Comment: What I have understood that since Russia is a single column in each dataframe there is an error. Now if that is the case can you correct my code?

Comment: @ambrishdhaka  Please check the updated code at the end of the solution post.  I would assume it to work fine

Comment: what about semi-colon `;` this is missing in your code. Is it not necessary?

Comment: @ambrishdhaka  `;` is required only if you are writting more than one statements  in a single line.  Here, I split it up for easier reading

Comment: Thanks! it is working fine. But can there be a generalized 1 liner that handles both the cases where there are 3 columns for 1 country or 1 column for a single country

Comment: @ambrishdhaka  The solution I provided works in all the cases